# Screen capturing inactive window

Tags: java, jna, screen-capture

Is it possible to get image contents of an obstructed window without bringing it to the front? Also, is it possible to send mouse clicks to a specific locations of such window? I want to do this in Java, using JNA, running Windows XP (if it is possible, would it also work on Windows 7?). If that can be done, would you mind telling me what functions will be needed and where can I read about it, because I have never worked with JNA yet. Thank you.

Comment: You are better off finding the Windows calls from someone who knows the Windows API.  Try asking another question with a Windows tag in order to find out how to do this through the Windows API using C.  When you get this information you can update this question with the C routines and we can help you call them through JNA.